# Mybb reputation system

Tags: javascript, css, mybb

Is there any possibility to make these javascript and css style work in MyBB Forums?
With this script, people can give improved reputation in posts. There are two buttons: thumbs up and thumbs down. When user hits thumbs up button, then thread/post author gets automatically +1 reputation and thumbs down, then gets author gets -1 reputation. Also it counts as percentage of all votes and shows how many votes are given when holding cursor on thumbs up or thumbs down button.

Css:

```
     .fa_vote, .fa_voted, .fa_count {
      font-size:12px;
      font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, Sans-serif;
      display:inline-block !important;
      width:auto !important;
      transition:300ms;
    }

    .fa_voted, .fa_vote:hover { opacity:0.4 }
    .fa_voted { cursor:default }

    .fa_count {
      font-weight:bold;
      margin:0 3px;
      cursor:default;
    }

    .fa_positive { color:#4A0 }
    .fa_negative { color:#A44 }

    .fa_votebar, .fa_votebar_inner {
      background:#C44;
      height:3px;
    }

    .fa_votebar_inner {
      background:#4A0;
      transition:300ms;
    }        .fa_vote, .fa_voted, .fa_count {
      font-size:12px;
      font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, Sans-serif;
      display:inline-block !important;
      width:auto !important;
      transition:300ms;
    }

    .fa_voted, .fa_vote:hover { opacity:0.4 }
    .fa_voted { cursor:default }

    .fa_count {
      font-weight:bold;
      margin:0 3px;
      cursor:default;
    }

    .fa_positive { color:#4A0 }
    .fa_negative { color:#A44 }

    .fa_votebar, .fa_votebar_inner {
      background:#C44;
      height:3px;
    }

    .fa_votebar_inner {
      background:#4A0;
      transition:300ms;
    }
```

Javacript:

```
        $(function() {
      // General Configuration of the plugin
      var config = {
        position_left : true, // true for left || false for right
        negative_vote : true, // true for negative votes || false for positive only
        vote_bar : true, // display a small bar under the vote buttons

        // button config
        icon_plus : '<img src="http://i18.servimg.com/u/f18/18/21/41/30/plus10.png" alt="+"/>',
        icon_minus : '<img src="http://i18.servimg.com/u/f18/18/21/41/30/minus10.png" alt="-"/>',

        // language config
        title_plus : 'Like %{USERNAME}\'s post',
        title_minus : 'Dislike %{USERNAME}\'s post',

        title_like_singular : '%{VOTES} person likes %{USERNAME}\'s post',
        title_like_plural : '%{VOTES} people like %{USERNAME}\'s post',

        title_dislike_singular : '%{VOTES} person dislikes %{USERNAME}\'s post',
        title_dislike_plural : '%{VOTES} people dislike %{USERNAME}\'s post',

        title_vote_bar : '%{VOTES} people liked %{USERNAME}\'s post %{PERCENT}'
      },


      // function bound to the onclick handler of the vote buttons
      submit_vote = function() {
        var next = this.nextSibling, // the counter next to the vote button that was clicked
            box = this.parentNode,
            bar = box.getElementsByTagName('DIV'),
            vote = box.getElementsByTagName('A'),
            mode = /eval=plus/.test(this.href) ? 1 : 0,
            i = 0, j = vote.length, pos, neg, percent;

        // submit the vote asynchronously
        $.get(this.href, function() {
          next.innerHTML = +next.innerHTML + 1; // add to the vote count
          next.title = next.title.replace(/(\d+)/, function(M, $1) { return +$1 + 1 });

          pos = +vote[0].nextSibling.innerHTML;
          neg = vote[1] ? +vote[1].nextSibling.innerHTML : 0;
          percent = pos == 0 ? '0%' : pos == neg ? '50%' : Math.round(pos / (pos + neg) * 100) + '%';

          if (bar[0]) {
            bar[0].style.display = '';
            bar[0].firstChild.style.width = percent;
            box.title = box.title.replace(/\d+\/\d+/, pos + '/' + ( pos + neg )).replace(/\(\d+%\)/, '(' + percent + ')');
          }
        });

        // revoke voting capabilities on the post once the vote is cast
        for (; i < j; i++) {
          vote[i].href = '#';
          vote[i].className = vote[i].className.replace(/fa_vote/, 'fa_voted');
          vote[i].onclick = function() { return false };
        }

        return false;
      },

      vote = $('.vote'), i = 0, j = vote.length,
      version = $('.bodylinewidth')[0] ? 0 : document.getElementById('wrap') ? 1 : $('.pun')[0] ? 2 : document.getElementById('ipbwrapper') ? 3 : 'badapple', // version check

      // version data so we don't have to redefine these arrays during the loop
      vdata = {
        tag : ['SPAN', 'LI', 'SPAN', 'LI'][version],
        name : ['.name', '.postprofile dt > strong', '.username', '.popmenubutton'][version],
        actions : ['.post-options', '.profile-icons', '.post-options', '.posting-icons'][version],
      },

      post, plus, minus, n_pos, n_neg, title_pos, title_neg, li, ul, bar, button, total, percent, span, pseudo, vote_bar; // startup variables for later use in the loop

      // prevent execution if the version cannot be determined
      if (version == 'badapple') {
        if (window.console) console.warn('This plugin is not optimized for your forum version. Please contact the support for further assistance.');
        return;
      }

      for (; i < j; i++) {
        post = $(vote[i]).parentsUntil('.post').parent()[0];
        bar = $('.vote-bar', vote[i])[0]; // vote bar
        button = $('.vote-button', vote[i]); // plus and minus buttons
        pseudo = $(vdata.name, post).text() || 'MISSING_STRING'; // username of the poster
        ul = $(vdata.actions, post)[0]; // post actions
        li = document.createElement(vdata.tag); // vote system container
        li.className = 'fa_reputation';

        if (li.tagName == 'SPAN') li.style.display = 'inline-block';

        // calculate votes
        if (bar) {
          total = +bar.title.replace(/.*?\((\d+).*/, '$1');
          percent = +bar.title.replace(/.*?(\d+)%.*/, '$1');

          n_pos = Math.round(total * (percent / 100));
          n_neg = total - n_pos;
        } else {
          n_pos = 0;
          n_neg = 0;
        }

        // set up negative and positive titles with the correct grammar, votes, and usernames
        title_pos = (n_pos == 1 ? config.title_like_singular : config.title_like_plural).replace(/%\{USERNAME\}/g, pseudo).replace(/%\{VOTES\}/g, n_pos);
        title_neg = (n_neg == 1 ? config.title_dislike_singular : config.title_dislike_plural).replace(/%\{USERNAME\}/g, pseudo).replace(/%\{VOTES\}/g, n_neg);

        // define the vote counts
        li.innerHTML = '<span class="fa_count fa_positive" title="' + title_pos + '">' + n_pos + '</span>' + (config.negative_vote ? '&nbsp;<span class="fa_count fa_negative" title="' + title_neg + '">' + n_neg + '</span>' : '');
        span = li.getElementsByTagName('SPAN'); // get the vote count containers for use as insertion points

        // create positive vote button
        plus = document.createElement('A');
        plus.href = button[0] ? button[0].firstChild.href : '#';
        plus.onclick = button[0] ? submit_vote : function() { return false };
        plus.className = 'fa_vote' + (button[0] ? '' : 'd') + ' fa_plus';
        plus.innerHTML = config.icon_plus;
        plus.title = (button[0] ? config.title_plus : title_pos).replace(/%\{USERNAME\}/g, pseudo);

        span[0] && li.insertBefore(plus, span[0]);

        // create negative vote button
        if (config.negative_vote) {
          minus = document.createElement('A');
          minus.href = button[1] ? button[1].firstChild.href : '#';
          minus.onclick = button[1] ? submit_vote : function() { return false };
          minus.className = 'fa_vote' + (button[1] ? '' : 'd') + ' fa_minus';
          minus.innerHTML = config.icon_minus;
          minus.title = (button[1] ? config.title_minus : title_neg).replace(/%\{USERNAME\}/g, pseudo);

          span[1] && li.insertBefore(minus, span[1]);
        }

        // create vote bar
        if (config.vote_bar) {
          vote_bar = document.createElement('DIV');
          vote_bar.className = 'fa_votebar';
          vote_bar.innerHTML = '<div class="fa_votebar_inner" style="width:' + percent + '%;"></div>';
          vote_bar.style.display = bar ? '' : 'none';
          li.title = config.title_vote_bar.replace(/%\{USERNAME\}/, pseudo).replace(/%\{VOTES\}/, n_pos + '/' + (n_pos + n_neg)).replace(/%\{PERCENT\}/, '(' + percent + '%)');
          li.appendChild(vote_bar);
        }

        // finally insert the vote system and remove the default one
        config.position_left ? ul.insertBefore(li, ul.firstChild) : ul.appendChild(li);
        vote[i].parentNode.removeChild(vote[i]);
      }
    });
```

I tried it different ways, but didn't figure it out.
Any help is welcome.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

The best way of doing so would be through creating an extension/plugin for MyBB. [MyBB 1.8 Documentation on plugin creation](https://docs.mybb.com/1.8/development/plugins/basics/).

But if you'd rather have a hacky solution, then it is possible to achieve this by placing that CSS and Javascript into MyBB's CSS and templates directly. That can be achieved through the Admin Control Panel -> Templates & Style -> Templates. The final template would depend on the page/set of pages where you want your code to appear. I suggest you read [documentation on templates](https://docs.mybb.com/1.8/development/themes/templates/) for that.

Hope it helps.